# Form onsubmit waits 5 seconds, then refreshes page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function executed when my form is submitted, with the onsubmit attribute. The page then just stalls for 5 seconds and refreshes. What is the problem?

```
 <form onsubmit='submitQuestion(quizType, $("#submitQ"), $("#submitA1"), $("#submitA2"), $("#submitA3"), $("#submitA4"), $("#submitCorrect"), $("#submitExpl"), $("#submitAuthor"), $("#submitDesc"), $("#submitDate"))'  method='POST'>
```

Inside the called function:

```
var submitQuestion = function (quizType, questionText, a1, a2, a3, a4, correctIndex, expl, author, desc, date) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "controller.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            quizType: quizType,
            addq_q: questionText,
            addq_a1: a1,
            addq_a2: a2,
            addq_a3: a3,
            addq_a4: a4,
            addq_correct: correctIndex,
            addq_expl: expl,
            addq_author: author,
                addq_desc: desc,
                addq_date: date,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to add `return false` to the function, and `return submitQuestion(...` to the `onsubmit` attribute. ***However*** you're sending jQuery objects in the AJAX request which isn't going to have the effect you expect. I'm assuming you want to send the `val()` instead?

Comment: I get a maximum call stack size exceeded error then.

Comment: I can't see anything in your code that refreshes the page. If it is in another piece of code called in the `success` event then it is probably waiting for the AJAX response to return. Have you looked at the network timings for the POST request? It'll probably be that taking 5 seconds.

Comment: There is such a thing as jQuery object? I thought it just holds a reference to the node.

Comment: @MattRink the refresh is triggered by the form submit itself and as the submit method doesn't return false and/or prevents default behavior, the page is refreshed as per default behavior.